# Format a sting in based on Divider symbol

Tags: c#

i have a string like this

4366|2d53|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|3f80|0|4248|295f|41c4|19c4|0|268

Here,
| - is denoted as a divider i want to make each divider consists exactly 4 charcters

Ex: 0|0 this must to be simplified as 0000|0000
    12|13 this must to be simplified as 0012|0013

Note:
  if the char. enclosed with | is less then 4 then add zero in front of the characters i.e. 12|13 is simplified as 0012|0013 not like this 1200|1300

Result:

4366|2d53|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|3f80|0|4248|295f|41c4|19c4|0|268

i want to convert this as

4366|2d53|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|3f80|0000|4248|295f|41c4|19c4|0000|2680

Comment: This smells like a homework excercise... Stack Overflow is not a coding service. What have you tried, and what didn't work? Hint: split the string using '|' as a delimiter, parse the parts as integer, format them as strings using leading zero's and join them again to a single string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
string.Join("|", myString.Split('|').Select(x => x.PadLeft(4,'0')));
```

I made a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uK1kyr

Answer (score 1):

That can be solved with simple string operations `Split()`, `PadLeft()` and `Join()`

```
string input = "4366|2d53|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|3f80|0|4248|295f|41c4|19c4|0|268";
string result = string.Join("|",input.Split('|').Select(x => x.PadLeft(4, '0')));
```